# WebRTC Recording Issue

Tags: reactjs, webrtc, recording, get-display-media

I have created video calling application using webrtc and i want to record the entire screen to provide recording feature. When I want to capture mediastream(getDisplayMedia) for recording,
it always ask permission.
But microsoft teams and other app never ask us for such permission if we want recording and do it internally. How can i achieve same type of recording as of MS-Teams . I mean without asking permission or is there any other way??

I am trying for some days but couldnot figure it out yet. It is built on Reactjs.

Comment: You mean the web version of Teams, or the dedicated installed app?

Comment: Yes..web version of Teams

Comment: "But microsoft teams and other app never ask us for such permission" - I think that's not correct. Browser doesn't allow to use hardware without the permission. Any web app that needs hardware access, it goes through that and it depends on user's response whether they allow it once or always

Comment: Have you simply checked the "always allow" checkbox when you were asked on Teams…?